# How to check with .validate an unknown number of inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I will have a form where there will be an unknown number of text inputs! 
The problem is that I have to control the inputs if they are valid.
Here is how I'm doing it:

```
<form action = "invita-utenti_.php" method = "POST" id="invita">
    <div id = "cont-nomi">
        <ul id = "utenti">          
            <?php
                $i = 2;
                while($i <= ($n_part)){                 
                    echo'
                        <li class = "utenti">
                             <label for="nome" class = "crea-camp-title"> Utente '.($i).' </label>
                                <input type = "text" name = "utente'.$i.'" id = "utente'.$i.'" size = "16" class = "utenti"  />
                        </li>';
                                $i++;                   
                    }               
            ?>
        </ul>
        <input type = "submit"<input type = "submit" value = "Invita" class = "reg-utenti" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the Js script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#invita").validate({
        rules: {
            utente2: 
                {required: true,
                remote : 'check_inviti.php' 
            }
        },
        messages : {
            utente2:
                {required:"inserire email o nome utente",
                remote: "inserire email o nome utente valido"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The *check_inviti.php* is ok.
The problem of this, how you can see, is that it checks only the ***"utente2"*** but it could be even a *"utente3" "utente4"* to get to a *"utente100"*

is there a fast way to check all the input fields without having to do a *while* in js (passing the variable through cookies)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [the plugin's `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to dynamically apply the rules.  All fields are targeted at once using a "starts with" selector attached to a jQuery `.each()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#invita").validate({   // initialize plugin on your form
        // other rules or options
    });

    $('input[name^="utente"]').each(function() {  // target all fields starting with "utente"
        $(this).rules('add', {  // declare the rules on each targeted field
            required: true,
            remote : 'check_inviti.php',
            messages : {
                required:  "inserire email o nome utente",
                remote: "inserire email o nome utente valido"
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's working!
Is there a way to use the 'input[name^="utente"]' in PHP?
In my php page I have something like this:
     $username = $_GET['utente2'];  
How can I do it for all users?

Comment: ok solved with:
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) 
   if (strpos($key, 'utente') === 0) 
    $username = $value; 

thank you!